Get User Information in Django
I have made a REST API using Django, and I have issues with retrieving a user's information by inserting a token.
I am using the User model.
So here is the view:
class getUserInfoView(APIView):

    #generics.RetrieveAPIView
    #authentication_classes = [authentication.TokenAuthentication]
    #authentication_classes = [jwt]
    #permission_classes = [permissions.IsAdminUser]
    #permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    #queryset = User.objects.all()
    #serializer_class = UsersListSerializer#UserSerializer
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]


    def get(self, request):

        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.user)
        user = request.user
        #return Response(UserSerializer(user).data)
        
        if serializer.is_valid():

            user = jwt.get_user(token=serializer.validated_data['access_token'])

            if user:

                return Response({
                    'id': user.id,
                    'username': user.username,
                    'email': user.email,
                })

            return Response({'detail': 'Invalid credentials'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
    
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

Here's the serializer:
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  
  #username = serializers.CharField(required=True)
  acess_token = serializers.UUIDField()

  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ["id", "username", "email"]

Here's the url:
path('api/me/', getUserInfoView.as_view(), name='Personal-Information')
The problem here is that when I run the server, I get the following:

I understand that the issue is in the view, can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?
Thank you.
I tried various View objects as argument for the class, did not work.

your api is secured with token authentication. you should pass a valid token in the header while trying to get the ep. Consider using Postman

remove permission_classes line and it should work for now
